# Prove that $\text{gcd}(a, p) = 1 \implies p\nmid a $ is true.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

This is one direction of the biconditional in part b of this proposition:

Prove that for every prime, $p$, and for all natural numbers $a$,
(a) $\text{gcd}(a,p)=p$ iff $p\mid a$
(b) $\text{gcd}(a,p)=1$ iff $p\nmid a$.

So far for my proof of part b, I have that:

Proposition Part (b): $\text{gcd}(a, p) = 1 \implies p\nmid a$.

Proof: Let us consider one direction of the bi-conditional proposition:
$p\nmid a \implies \text{gcd}(a, p) = 1$. 
Let $b$ be a common divisor of $a$ and $p$. It is enough to show that $b = 1$. 
We know that $p$ is prime, so if $b \mid p, b = 1$ or $b = p$. 
If $b = p$, then $p\mid a$ because $b$ is a common divisor of both $a$ and $p$. This is a contradiction, because we assumed that $p \nmid a$. 
Therefore, $b = 1$.

Now I just need the proof of the other direction; please help me out!

Comment: The other direction is trivial. If $\gcd(a,p) =1$ then no factor of $p$ divides $a$.  In particular $p\not \mid a$.

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to prove that $[\gcd(a,p)=1]\Rightarrow [p\nmid a]$ you could equivalently prove $[p\mid a]\Rightarrow [\gcd(a,p)\neq1]$, which I think you will find easier. If you know that $p\mid a$ then both $p$ and $a$ are divisible by $p$, so the $\gcd(a,p)=p$.

Comment: So basically, I should use the contrapositive to prove this statement?

Comment: @Chimin You do not **have** to, but it should be a reflex to check the contrapositive to see if it is easier whenever you are working on if and only if statements.

Comment: not exactly following how this proves that [gcd(a,p)=1]⇒[p∤a]

Comment: @Chimin So you are familiar with the logical equivalence between a statement and its contrapositive? If I prove the contrapositive then the original statement has also been proven. And the point is that if you get to assume that $p\mid a$ (which is exactly the hypothesis of the contrapositive) then it is immediately apparent that $\gcd(a,p)\neq 1$. The fact that we can further show the exact value of $\gcd(a,p)$ is sort of just icing on the cake.

Comment: Yes; is it enough to say:

Comment: If we know that p | a, then both p and a are divisible by p, so the gcd(a, p) = p. The only possible common divisors of a and p are 1 and p. We know that p is the largest number that can possibly satisfy this statement, thus p ≠ 1.

Comment: @Chimin You don't need to say that $p\neq 1$, because you know that $p$ is prime. All we care about is showing that the $\gcd(a,p)\neq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

$p|p$ and if $p|a$ then $p$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $p$.  But the greatest common factor is $1$ so this is impossible.

This direction was meant to be trivial. For positive integers $a|b \iff \gcd(a,b) = a$.  If $a|b$ then its a common divisor but nothing larger than $a$ divides $a$.  If $\gcd(a,b) = a$ then $a|b$.

Answer (score 0):

If $p|a$ and also $p|p$ $\Rightarrow p|gcd(a,p)$ as $gcd(a,p)=ax+py, x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$ $\rightarrow \leftarrow $ because $p\not \mid 1$

Comment: unless it is $p=\pm1$

Comment: where did x and y come from

Comment: $x$ and $y$ both are integre numbers. I recommend reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bézout%27s_identity

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $ $ note that $\ p = (a,p) \iff p\mid (a,p) \iff  p\mid a,p \iff  p\mid a,\, $ so $(a)$ is true.

Negating above $\,p\nmid a\iff (a,p)\neq p\iff (a,p)=1,\, $ by $\, (a,p)\mid p,\, $ so $(b)$ is true.

Comment: Note $\,(a,b)$ denotes $\,\gcd(a,b),\,$ standard notation in number theory.